# how to make a textview that change automatically after some seconds

Tags: java, android

I want to make a text view that will update the text after 12 seconds randomly from an array list, automatically.
My code is not working well, it just changes the text one time but I want it to change it every 12 sec.
Here is is the onCreate method of my fragment:

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        TextView topStatus_tv = root.findViewById(R.id.TopStatus);

        String[] topStatus = {
                "Hello ", //0
                "Welcome to your PERSONAL DICTIONARY",//1
                "Hi Whats up beauty?",//2
                "Good Evening, sir",//3
                "how is the Weather",//4
                "Get Motivated, go on",//5
                "By upgrading your second language, open your mind and be more clever",//6
                "Practice everyday!",//7
                "Make good habits",//8
                "Your HABITS will make a good person from you,\nnot just your Believes",//9
                "Knock knock! who is it?\nits the programmer needs your donation",//10
                "First make a good Believe, then make good habits\n(Good does not mean perfect)",//11
                "Decrease blaming, increase accepting",//12
                "You know? sometimes im tired from everything. ",//13
                "Music is strange, isn't it?",//14
                "you wanna see someone weird? goto setting, press donate button and choose 1000$.\nthen go look at the mirror",//15
                "Spotify, IM COMING FOR YOU!!!",//16
                "Don't work too much.\ngo hangout with your friends, their idiots",//17
                "you know? In parallel worlds you are coding and I am using your app",//18
                "When you are in a good mood, the world has to give you what you want",//19
                "make a wall from others goodness.\nwhen they make a mistake, take one brick from wall, don't break it."//20
        };

    

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    int random = new Random().nextInt(20);
                    topStatus_tv.setText(topStatus[random]);
                }
            }, 12000);
        }


        return root;
    }
```

Comment: not the downvoter, just saying that there are a ton of resources available for doing what you're doing, also - android studio is just an ide, it just helps you to write your apps, so unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE, there's no need to use it as a tag

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks for being nice, i didnt know that mistake.sorry. anyway i still cant solve my problem can you explain or write answer in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your `Runnable` to a variable. Then use the variable in `postDelayed`. At the end of your `run()` function call `postDelayed` with the `Runnable`-variable again with 12 seconds.

Remove your `for` loop and use a counter variable to limit the number of repetitions.

Something like this (without the counter):

```
class YourActivity {
    // ...
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable;

    public View onCreateView() {
        // ...
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int random = new Random().nextInt(20);
                topStatus_tv.setText(topStatus[random]);
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 12000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 12000);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry my english is not good enough , can you explain it more? and i dont want limit for it... the 100 number in my for loop is just a high number(dirty code)

Comment: @mortezanaji ok, then this should work for you as is. It will repeat forever. Every 12 seconds.

Comment: your code has problem. it says ('runnable' might not have been initialized). but we have this line  Runnable runnable = new Runnable()  .i dont understand why its getting error

Comment: Well yeah, you'd have to declare `handler` and `runnable` as class member variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227457/discussion-between-jox-and-morteza-naji).

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to the textView and use onClickListener in your java code and setTime